# Unit Testing Contract That Relies on block.number

Tags: contract-development, openzeppelin, hardhat, unittesting

It seems to be recommended to use `block.number` over `block.timestamp` for time-based operations (see [Block Timestamp Manipulation: Preventative Techniques](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/09smart-contracts-security.asciidoc))

OpenZeppelin provides some APIs to simulate [passing time](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/test-helpers/0.5/api#time). However, `time.advaneBlockTo(target)` is extremely slow, so unit testing a contract that uses `block.number`  to simulate any large amount of time (say, 1 month) with this API will be prohibitively slow for the purpose of unit tests.

Are there any faster alternatives to simulate increasing `block.number` as a means of simulating the passage of time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- Hardhat's `evm_mine` where your test.js file would look like this:

  ```
   const hre = require("hardhat") 
   ...
   //Do operation on block #N

   await hre.network.provider.send("evm_mine");

   //Do operation on block #N+1
   //Test
  ```
- Use OpenZeppelin's test helper `advanceBlock`  where your test.js file would look like this:

  ```
   const { time } = 
   require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers');
   ...
   //Do something on block #N

   await time.advanceBlock();

   //Do something on block #N+1
   //Test
  ```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. Yes, you can use those APIs, however the issue is that they are very slow.

For example, if a contract assumes average block time is 3s and wants to check if 30 days have passed, then it needs to check block #N+864000 (30 days * 24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds / 3 seconds-per-block).

Looping 864,000 and calling `advanceBlock` or `evm_mine` is not feasible for a unit test, so I am looking for alternatives.